# php login script can't be loaded

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm new to php and i need help with this code, because i get "HTTP-fout 500 (Internal Server Error):" when i try to load it. Could someone post the whole good code. thanks.

```
  <?php
session_start();


if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$notifications[] = 'Login failed! Please provide a username and password.';
   }

   if(count($notifications) == 0) {
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=####;host=####',   
'####', '####');

    $sql = "SELECT username, verified FROM users WHERE username = :username AND    
password = :password";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':username'    => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => md5($_POST['password'])
    ));

    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result) {
        // Set session details and redirect user to members page
        session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username']=':username';
    $_SESSION['password']=':password';

        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $notifications[] = "Username or Password incorrect.";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you might want to blank out your database login details...

Comment: At first glance, you have a try block without a catch block.  Have you tried running php -l <your script name> from the command line?  That would tell you if there are any parse errors.

Comment: Please share with us any troubleshoting you have done so far, so that we have less guesswork to do. The first step is tryng to locate where the error occurs (which line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few curly braces. Not sure if this is the cause of your issue but try this out. The third and forth lines added set the error reporting to display on the current page instead of logging it to file / syslog / etc.

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $notifications[] = 'Login failed! Please provide a username and password.';
}

if(count($notifications) == 0) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=####;host=####','####', '####');
        $sql = "SELECT username, verified FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':username'    => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => md5($_POST['password'])
        ));

        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($result) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['username']=':username';
            $_SESSION['password']=':password';

            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $notifications[] = "Username or Password incorrect.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i still get the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in the top of your script, your page will now display all the information about what went wrong =)

With that information others can help you more easily, and it will help you to learn/find your mistakes

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: where can i see the errors ?

Comment: On the page self =), instead of 500 message you will get a page with some error details.